# How does an Iterated Integral Work?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am simply confused because of planes now.

Consider:

$$J = \int_{R}\int_{R} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dxdy$$

What is the geometrical aspect of this integral?

This represents the volume under $h(x,y) = e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$ I believe.

Then how is:

$$I = \int_{R} e^{-x^2} dx = \int_{R} e^{-y^2} dy$$?

How does that statement hold true? Which are independent/dependent variables? I am utterly confused.

Comment: The formula involving $I$ seems to be just a definition of $I$. The second equality is trivially true: It reflects the fact that it doesn't matter what letter you use for the integration variable in an integral. The *interesting* question is why is $J=I^2$ …

Comment: It actually is true. Here:http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/69832.html

Comment: Yes. $J = I^2$ is the fact. But I dont understand, in the $xy$ plane then, is $y$ the dependent variable for $x$? How does this work?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, can you please help me? I am very confused.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, if we use $J = I^2$ then the iterated integral 3D representation is that $x$ is related to $y$ which is not supposed to be the intial beginning. Any help?

Comment: I'm hoping that someone else will step up and explain it. I am very bad at clearing up confusions at this level, unless I have the confused person and a blackboard at hand.

Comment: Er, no, there is no relation indicated between $x$ and $y$ except that they occur in a similar manner in the formula.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, nobody would like to help I suppose. Thanks for trying though. I meant, when you have $h(x,y) = e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$ then you have some part of the surface **in** the $xy$ plane wouldnt you? Does that indicate $x$ is related to $y$?

Comment: The surface is $z=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$. No, it does not touch the $xy$-plane. At all points $(x,y)$ we have $z>0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  I think I need to go back and study surfaces. Thank you! So $x$ and $y$ are both **independent and unrelated** variables right?

Comment: Correct. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks, then just a question. In the 3D plane though, how do you define the axes? In other words, what are the respetive axes for our problem?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I would appreicate any idea whatsoever. Thank you

Comment: The axes are the usual ones in the 3D-space. The $x$-axis consists of the points $(x,0,0)$, $x$ anym the $y$-axis of the points $(0,y,0)$, $y$ any, and the $z$-axis of the points $(0,0,z)$, $z$ any. Are you at all familiar with the 3-dimensional coordinate system?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I thought I was upto now. So, the axes, dont have to be related? Then so the axes in a plane are unrelated? You have two functions correct?

$$f(t) = e^{-t^2}$$
$$h(x) = e^{-x^2}$$

Then you **define a new function**

$$g(x,t) = e^{-(t^2 + x^2)}$$

So the axes dont have to be related? How does a 3D system work?

The problem is if we **only have f** and not $h$ etc then we do not have a 3d system. Because $t$ and $x$ would lie in the same axis. So we need $h$ and $f$ seperately dont we?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$$

This is an important integral in probability theory, so it pays to understand what is happening here.  You can't get the indefinite integral in terms of elementary functions, but you can find the value of the integral with limits $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

First, the statement that you are confused about is, as Harald says, merely a matter of switching what you call the integration variable; that does not change the value of the integral.  Try it:  What is 
$$
\int_0^1 x\, dx$$ and what is
$$\int_0^1 v\, dv$$
You can see the integration variable disappears in the end.

Next, why in the world are we introducing that equivalent but differently "named" integral 
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2} dy$? We are doing it just so that we can multiply the two integrals together, getting 
$$
I^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2} dy
$$
and then since when doing the $x$ integral the entire $y$ integral is just a constant (it does not depend on $x$, after all), we can re-write this as a double integral
$$I^2 = \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)} dy\,dx $$

Why is this progress?  The trick is (and I like to think of this as having been discovered by Gauss, but probably others did this before him) that this double integral is over the whole $x,y$ plane, and we can therefore easily transform to polar coordinates, because the limits will be $r$ going from $0$ to $\infty$ and $\theta$ from 
$0$ to $2\pi$.

The $(x^2+y^2)$ is conveniently $r^2$, and -- here is the zinger -- 
$$
dx\,dy -\longrightarrow r\,d\theta\,dr $$

That extra factor of $r$ is golden because now we can do the integral:
$$
I^2 = \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{r=0}^{\infty} r e^{-r^2} dr
= 2\pi \left[ -\frac{1}{2} e^{-r^2} \right]_{r=0}^{r=\infty} = \pi(1-0) = \pi
$$
SO $$
I = \sqrt{\pi}$$